# Problem 53 in Real Analysis (4th edition) Chapter 16 by Royden

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be Hilbert space and $K\in L(H,H)$ be a compact operator. Show that $T=K^*K$ is compact and symmetric. Then use the
Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem to show that there is an orthonormal sequence $\{\varphi_k\}$ of $H$ such that $T(\varphi_k)=\lambda_k \varphi_k$ for all $k$ and $T(h)=0$ if $h$ is orthogonal to $\{\varphi_k\}$. Conclude that if $h$ is orthogonal to $\{\varphi_k\}$, then $K(h)=0$.

Define $H_0$ to be the closed linear span of $\{K^m(\varphi_k),m\ge 1,k\ge 1\}$, Show that $H_0$ is closed and separable, $K(H_0)\subset H_0$ and $K=0$ on $H_0^\perp$.

I find some difficulty in proving the last result that $K=0$ on $H_0^\perp$ despite the remaining part of this problem being solvable for me.

Comment: If $h\in H_0^\perp$ then $\langle h,K^m\phi_k\rangle=0$ for all $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, $h\perp\phi_k$, hence $Kh=0$ by the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In my viewpoint, due to the very fact that $<h,K^m\varphi_k>=0$ only for $m\geq1$, we can not conclude that $h\perp\varphi_k$.

Comment: I don't have the book with me. Does $k$ start from 0?

Comment: Misunderstood. I think one can conclude $\langle K^*h,\phi_k\rangle=0$ and hence $KK^*h=0$. Then $\langle h,KK^*h\rangle =0$ so $K^*h=0$. But I don't see how this implies $Kh=0$. In fact, I think it is wrong if you take $K=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\cr0&0\end{pmatrix}$ (where $\phi_1=\mathbf{j}$ and $H_0=Span(\mathbf{i})$).

Comment: I agree with you that $m$ starting from 0 is sufficient for this conclusion to  hold.

Answer (score 0):

As Chrystomath noted, for any $h \in H_0^\perp$:
$\langle h, K(\phi_k) \rangle =\langle K^*(h),\phi_k \rangle  = 0$ for all $k$, so $K^*(h)$ is orthogonal to $\{\phi_k\}$. Thus $K(K^*(h)) = 0$. Then $||K^*(h)||^2 = \langle K^*(h), K^*(h) \rangle = \langle KK^*(h), h \rangle = 0$, so we have $K^*(h) =0$.